# Sending the JSON response as array or normal object

Tags: json

I am implementing a restful service where I am getting the pdf names and their ids from the database in the JSON fromat. Which one of the both the convenient JSON resful service response?

**First Option:**

```
{
    "results": {
        "documentNames": [
            "test.pdf",
            "ireport-ultimate-guide.pdf",
            "sending report.pdf",
            "Motor Hour.pdf"
        ],
        "documentds": [
            21116,
            21117,
            21118,
            21119
        ]
    }
}
```

**Second Option:**

```
{
    "results": {
        "21116": "test.pdf",
        "21117": "ireport-ultimate-guide.pdf",
        "21118": "sending report.pdf",
        "21119": "Motor Hour.pdf"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this "third option": The *result* is a *list* of *object*.

```
   {
    "result": [{
            "id": "21116",
            "filename": "test.pdf"
        },
        {
            "id": "21117",
            "filename": "ireport-ultimate-guide.pdf"
        },
        {
            "id": "21118",
            "filename": "sending report.pdf"
        },
        {
            "id": "21119",
            "filename": "Motor Hour.pdf"
        }
    ]
}
```

because it better models the object structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an entity for each document that contains both name and I'd.

```
[
    {"name": "doc_1", "id": 123},
    {"name": "doc_2", "id": 456}
]
```